# Configuring nose tests for different test targets

Tags: python, testing, nose, nosetests, system-testing

I have a set of nose tests which I use to test a piece of hardware. For example, the test below is concerned with testing the alarm for each mode on the system:

```
import target

modes = ("start","stop","restart","stage1","stage2")
max_alarm_time = 10

# generate tests for testing each mode
def test_generator():
    for m in modes:
        yield check_alarm, m, max_alarm_time 

# test alarm for a mode
def check_alarm(m, max_alarm_time):
    target.set_mode(m)
    assert target.alarm() < max_alarm_time
```

Most of my tests have this appearance where I am testing a particular function for all `modes` on the system.

I now wish to use the same set of tests to test a new piece of hardware which has two extra modes:

```
modes = ("start","stop","restart","stage1","stage2","stage3","stage4")
```

Of course, I want my tests to still work for the old hardware also. When running automated test I will need to hardcode, for the test environment, the hardware I am connected to.

I believe the best way to do this is to create a paramaters.py module as follows:

```
def init(hardware):
    global max_alarm_time
    global modes
    max_alarm_time = 10
    if hardware == "old":
       modes = ("start","stop","restart","stage1","stage2")
    elif hardware == "new":
       modes = ("start","stop","restart","stage1","stage2","stage3","stage4")
```

with test_alarms.py now looking like this instead:

```
import target
import parameters

# generate tests for testing each mode
def test_generator():
    for m in parameters.modes:
        yield check_alarm, m, parameters.max_alarm_time 

# test alarm for a mode
def check_alarm(m, max_alarm_time):
    target.set_mode(m)
    assert target.alarm() < max_alarm_time
```

Then in my main I have the following:

```
import nose
import parameters

parameters.init("new") 

nose.main()
```

Is this a valid approach in your opinion?

Answer (score 0):

An alternative way to solve a similar problem is to abuse the `@attr` decorator from the attribute plugin in the following way:

```
from nose.plugins.attrib import attr

max_alarm_time = 10

# generate tests for testing each mode
@attr(hardware='old')
@attr(modes = ("start","stop","restart","stage1","stage2"))
def test_generator_old():
    for m in test_generator_old.__dict__['modes']:
        yield check_alarm, m, max_alarm_time 

@attr(hardware='new')
@attr(modes = ("start","stop","restart","stage1","stage2", "stage3","stage4"))
def test_generator_new():
    for m in test_generator_new.__dict__['modes']:
        yield check_alarm, m, max_alarm_time 


# test alarm for a mode
def check_alarm(m, max_alarm_time):
    print "mode=", m
```

You can immediately switch between 'old' and 'new',like this:

```
$ nosetests modes_test.py -a hardware=new -v
modes_test.test_generator_new('start', 10) ... ok
modes_test.test_generator_new('stop', 10) ... ok
modes_test.test_generator_new('restart', 10) ... ok
modes_test.test_generator_new('stage1', 10) ... ok
modes_test.test_generator_new('stage2', 10) ... ok
modes_test.test_generator_new('stage3', 10) ... ok
modes_test.test_generator_new('stage4', 10) ... ok

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 7 tests in 0.020s

OK
```

And the old one:
$ nosetests modes_test.py -a hardware=old -v

```
modes_test.test_generator_old('start', 10) ... ok
modes_test.test_generator_old('stop', 10) ... ok
modes_test.test_generator_old('restart', 10) ... ok
modes_test.test_generator_old('stage1', 10) ... ok
modes_test.test_generator_old('stage2', 10) ... ok

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 5 tests in 0.015s

OK
```

Also, although I have not played with it that much, [nose-testconfig](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/nose-testconfig/) could help you to do the same trick.

Comment: Isn't it better to define my modes in one place since I'm using them in all my tests? Should the modes change for the new hardware for example, I would then only need to change the definition in one place rather than having to change all tests.

Comment: It comes down to the ratio of tests/hardware types. I see nothing wrong with what you did - as long as it works for you!